# Android - sharing SSO cookies between app.

Tags: android, cookies, webview, sharedpreferences

For few last days I am trying to share SSO session cookies between two applications developed by myself. I've tried so many options and tutorials.

**Getting cookies from App1:**

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
String cookie = cookieManager.getCookie(url);
```

I've tried with cookies from exact url from onPageFinished (of WebViewClient) and:

```
Uri uri1 = Uri.parse(url);
String uriGetHost = uri1.getHost();
```

On the other hand, how to send cookies to another app? I've done this with bundle. Any better ideas?

**Setting cookie in App2:**

```
if(cookieList!=null) {
    CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
    for(int i=0; i<cookieList.size();i++){
        cookieManager.setCookie(hostList.get(i),cookieList.get(i));
    }
    tubeView.loadUrl(videoURL);
} else{
    tubeView.loadUrl(getString(R.string.myURL));
}
```

I am doing it right after getting cookies in bundle.

Comment: used `ContentProvider` for that.